# Meta title and description are not being used with share button. Are they still supported? Or are they grabbing a cached version of my page?

Tags: caching, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, facebook-sharer

My daily deal site dynamically updates about once a day.

I'm using the meta og: title, description, and image tags on my front page, but when I press the share button, the description and image are outdated - it usually seems to show the previous day's deal (description and image).

Is it reading from a cached version of my page?  How can I fix this or force it to get the current page?

(My site: http://sbsaver.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and enter your URL to refresh Facebook's cache.

Answer (score 0):

The meta-data and description are supposed to describe the page, not the transient content. So Facebook isn't inclined to grab daily updates. After all, the data should rarely be changing.

If you want the Facebook social graph to incorporate all of your deals, you'll have to assign a new URL to each one.

You might be able to force updates by submitting your homepage to the Facebook "linter" tool every day; but that's not guaranteed to work. And what would your customers think if they "like" one item one day, and they see a completely different item in their profile later? "When did I ever like THAT? Am I being spammed?" is the response I would expect.

David

Comment: I'm actually using a share button, not a like button - so I want the user to be able to share the daily deal.  I actually created a cron job to ping the lint tool with my Url every morning.   It seemed to work so far.